Accessing element 2D numpy array Python: A[i][j] vs A[i,j]
I learn to accessing element of 2D numpy array in Python.
A=np.array([[6,4,2],[-7,2,0]])
print(A)
print(A[1][0])
print(A[1,0])

The result is:
[[ 6  4  2]
 [-7  2  0]]
-7
-7

We can see that A[1][0] and A[1,0] is equal. So, which one the best uses for accessing 2D element in 2D numpy array? What difference uses between A[i][j] and A[i,j]?
